# How to GetSheetByName using partial string in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use .getSheetByName('') to grab a sheet whose name contain a certain string like, 'V1' or 'V4', not an exact match. Say the name of the sheet is '2020 0304 V1', the first part is always changing but it contains V1, I tried .getSheetByName('*V1') but it is not working. Any hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Issue and workaround:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, the method like the regex cannot be used with `getSheetByName()`. So in this case, it is required to use the workarounds.

In this answer, I would like to propose 2 patterns.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, `test` is used for searching the sheet name. `getSheetName()` is used for retrieving the sheet name. In this case, it supposes that the pattern is like `2020 0304 V1`.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const searchText = "V1";
  
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  const regex = RegExp(`\\d{4} \\d{4} ${searchText}`);
  const sheet = sheets.filter(s => regex.test(s.getSheetName()));
  if (sheet.length > 0) console.log(sheet[0].getSheetName());
}
```

- In this case, if there is only one sheet which has the sheet name of the pattern of `\d{4} \d{4} V1` in your Spreadsheet, you can retrieve the sheet by `sheet[0]`.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, `includes` is used for searching the sheet name. `getSheetName()` is used for retrieving the sheet name.

#### Sample script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const searchText = "V1";

  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  const sheet = sheets.filter(s => s.getSheetName().includes(searchText));
  if (sheet.length > 0) console.log(sheet[0].getSheetName());
}
```

- In this case, if there is only one sheet which has the sheet name including `V1` in your Spreadsheet, you can retrieve the sheet by `sheet[0]`.

### Note:

- In this case, please enable V8 at the script editor.

### References:

- [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetname)
- [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)